# StackNavigator's goBack with nested BottomTabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm using React Navigation 5.x in React Native 0.61.x. The goal is for the navigation's goBack functionality to behave like Android's default back button.
In the example below user lands on Profile page, which is inside StackNavigator.

Clicking the button navigates to BottonTabNavigator with 2 tabs. After switching between tabs, I'd expect goBack to behave like Android's hardware back button, which navigates user to the last visible tab. When BottomTabNavigator's history stack is empty, it goes to Profile page.
However, clicking on back arrow from StackNavigator's header navigates back to the starting page again.

I tried dispatching goBack event instead of calling the function directly. I passed null to it, tried using route key values among other things. 
Is there any elegant solution that would not involve me esentially writing my own routing logic? I know for a fact that top level navigator is aware of bottom one's history and available routes.

Here's a link to working example and the code:

https://snack.expo.io/rJ64JkgDI

App.js

```
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

var Stack = createStackNavigator();
var Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function Feed() {
    return <View><Text>Feed</Text></View>;
}

function Profile({navigation}){
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        Profile
      </Text>
      <Button title="test" onPress={() => { navigation.navigate("Home")} }></Button>
    </View>);
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Messages" component={Messages} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function Messages() {
  return <View><Text>Messages</Text></View>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset the stack navigation or directly call the page you want to go to with stack navigation like this:

```
 this.props.navigation.dispatch(
   StackActions.reset({
     index: 0,
     actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Feed" })]
   })
 );
```